# CouchDB bulk delete Node.js

Tags: json, node.js, couchdb, cloudant, document-database

I am using the Cloudant node module to modify my Cloudant database. I am sending the following documents to the [db.bulk(params,callback) function.](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-nano#dbbulkdocs-params-callback)

```
{ docs: [
   { "_id": "...",
     "_rev": "...",
    "_deleted": true
   },
   { "_id": "...",
     "_rev": "...",
    "_deleted": true
   },
   { "_id": "...",
     "_rev": "...",
    "_deleted": true
   },
   { ... }   
]}
```

After I call this function I do not get any errors but when I try and query the database later I am still getting the deleted documents back? I know that Cloudant has "tombstone documents" so they should still be there but I don't really see tombstones at all I just see the documents I wanted to delete sitting in my database with a new _rev number and returned as if they are still active.

Even when I try to query the database with a selector deleted: true I get nothing back.

Am I missing something?

P.S If you are wondering why I put "_deleted" in the bulk document I was just following what [this site said to do.](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API)

Comment: In a bulk operation, some changes may fail while others succeed. Did you check the actual response rather than just the `err` parameter?

Comment: Yes I did and it passes back the _id and _rev number for each document which is the expected behavior for deleting documents according to the documentation [on this page](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API).

Comment: And when you query them later, do they have the _rev that was returned, the original _rev, or something else?

Comment: Okay hang on I must have changed something a minute ago because I just checked the response for the documents and now it is telling me I have a document update conflict.

Comment: Ahh found it! The method I just added modified some of the documents so the _rev number was out of date. Thank you @OrangeDog I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a bulk operation, some changes may fail while others succeed.

You need to check the actual response for each update rather than just the `err` parameter. Even if `err` is `null`, it may be the case that every update failed for an individual reason, for example a revision conflict.